what should be the minimum distance between two MOSFETs on same heatsink
i am placing two MOSFETs on the same heatsink for reducing the thermal losses and making the design compact. What should be the distance between the two MOSFETs.

There is no definite answer to your question. It's a trade-off between thermal performance and size. Also, without knowing the package of those MOSFETs, we really don't have enough information to even suggest a distance. For example, if they are TO220 packages, I could suggest 0.1 inch (2.54 mm) separation. But, again, that's just a suggestion out of thin air.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Are they at the same voltage?

The mosfets have higher conduction loss the hotter they are. So, I'm not quite sure how reducing the cooling they get will "reduce thermal losses". You're not trying to build a heater, right? Can you please clarify what you mean by "reducing the thermal losses"?

This question can't be answered in it's current form. It depends on the power dissipated in the mosfets, the heatsink's thermal resistance, airflow, ambient temperature, and more.

Well, should the MOSFETs be thermally coupled?  Should they be thermally decoupled?  Are they typically losing energy at the same point of time, alternatingly, or uncorrelatedly?
What is your goal?  Maximizing heat transfer?  Minimizing operating temperature?  What is the geometry of your heat sink?  What are its thermal characteristics?  How much heat energy are we talking about here?  Do you use fan cooling or not?
How do you hope to "reduce the thermal losses"?  That's not the primary purpose of heat sinks: their task is to avoid a buildup in temperature.  If you want to reduce thermal losses, you may want to package your circuit in styrofoam or other insulators (indeed there are things like quartz oscillators where you want to achieve a certain operating temperature where this can be part of the thermal design to reduce the power needed for heating the oscillator).  But I very much suspect that you don't want to reduce the thermal losses (which is mainly a question of circuit design rather than heat sinks) but reduce their consequences on the temperature of the MOSFETs.
